# StreamSource problem with FileInputStream vs File

Tags: xsd, filestream

SAX error if StreamSource(FileInputStream) but StreamSource(File) ok

Hi, I encountered a StreamSource issue when the parameter was FileInputStream.
When the parameter was File, it's ok.

```
 public int initXSD (String xsdFile) {

        // no error at all if File
  Source schemaFile = new StreamSource(new File(xsdFile));

        // sax error at newSchema() if FileInputStream
  Source schemaFile = new StreamSource( new FileInputStream(new File(xsdFile))); 

  SchemaFactory factory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);


     Schema schema = factory.newSchema(schemaFile);
  validator = schema.newValidator();
  return 0;
 }
```

as soon as i changed the StreamSource line to take a FileInputStream:

```
Source schemaFile = new StreamSource( new FileInputStream(new File(xsdFile)));
```

I got a sax error at newSchema():

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: src-resolve: Cannot resolve the name 's:ComplexObjectType' to a(n) 'type definition' component.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public int initXSD (String xsdFile) {

    // no error at all if File 
    Source schemaFile = new StreamSource(new File(xsdFile));

    // sax error at newSchema() if FileInputStream 
    Source schemaFile = new StreamSource( new FileInputStream(new File(xsdFile))); 

    Schema schema = factory.newSchema(schemaFile); 
    validator = schema.newValidator(); 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: this is the fix?